# Two States -> Two Actions -> One UIButton for iOS 7

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, uibutton

I want to accomplish something that It's even hard for me to explain to you, but I'm going yo try to do.

I have one `UIButton` (**Button 1**) and want it do to two different actions depending on the *context* or *state* of this particular button, but the *context* or *state* is controlled by another `UIButton` (**Button 2**).

I hope this image can explain what I'm looking for:

[image]

Now... i'm not looking for the exact code I need to implement, but an idea of how to accomplish this, maybe some hint about some methods or classes to use.

Note: I already think about to change the `UIButton` tag to control the action, but I can't change the tag because I need it as it is to control the behavior of actions. Also, (**Button1**) must return to it's original state once the second action it's used.

Comment: If you can't use the tag, I would recommend subclassing UIButton and simply storing the state

Comment: why can't you wire the button to the same method and do different things there depending on the state?

Comment: @SVD do you mean maybe checking if the button has or not certain color for background before to execute the action or something like that?

Comment: I could be misunderstanding you but couldn't you simply set a Bool or enum when button two is pressed to indicate the current state. Then when the user pressed button one it determines what to do based on this state? Basing business logic on button colour values is not very advisable :)

Comment: If you decide not to check the button state, you an always use a boolean flag, i totally agree with @bennythemink

Comment: I like your approach @bennythemink but how can I keep the second button pressed in iOS (I have no idea how to do that). Do I have to use an specific IBAction or using UIControlState?

Comment: @DaveGomez I do not know your exact circumstances but it seems to me like you should be using a button and a UISwitch. The switch is used to define the context/state and should be used instead of button two. When button one is pressed it determines what to do based on the 'on' property (a boolean) of the switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you've described, I suggest you should have two IBActions and set a property of UIButton 1. Your .h header file will look something like -

```
-(IBAction)button1Pressed:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)button2Pressed:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton* button1;
```

Where the button1 property is hooked up to your button one via ctrl-drag in the interface builder.

Then within your .m implementation file, the following set-up will enable you to do what you're looking for.

```
-(IBAction)button2Pressed:(id)sender{

if (self.button1.selected){

self.button1.selected = NO;

}else

self.button1.selected = YES;


}
```

So when you press button2, this will change the state of button1 by making it 'selected' or not, which means button1 will do what ever you need, where the state is controlled by button2.

```
-(IBAction)button1Pressed:(id)sender{

if (self.button1.selected){

//Place your code here for button 1 to do something in this state

} else

//Place your code here for button 1 to do something in this UN-selected state
```

}

I hope this helps with what you're trying to do.
Thanks, Jim.

Comment: Really easy, I was thinking to do something a lot more complicated =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UIButton's UIControlState, with if statements.

(i.e

```
buttton.selected....
buttton.enabled.....
buttton.highlighted....
```

)

if I understand correctly?